# how to solve the extited code 139, for run the image cloudera/quickstart, in docker with WSL2 Ubuntu?

Tags: image, docker, ubuntu, wsl-2, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I'm using WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04 distribution, and I was trying create a container in Docker with the Following command:

```
docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -it -v $PWD:/src --publish-all=true -p 8888:8888 -p 8080:8080 -p 7180:7180 cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

when I run this command, a download started with a weight of about 4.4 GB, (i think that is because because was the first time that I run this container), whe the download was over, I used the following command to check the containers `docker ps -a` and the status for the container is `Exited (139) 6 minutes ago`, when check my image list

```
    REPOSITORY            TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
uracilo/hadoop        latest    902e5bb989ad   8 months ago   727MB
cloudera/quickstart   latest    4239cd2958c6   4 years ago    6.34GB
```

I think that the image was created successfully, but when I try to run the first command, I keep gettind the `Exited (139)` in the status and I can't use the container

Apparently the exit code 139 refers to some problem with the system or the hardware, maybe the RAM, but I'm not sure. and I don't know if this problem is because I'm using wsl or my 8GB in ram
not enough to run the image

is there any way to run this image successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a file named .wslconfig under `%userprofile%` folder on your Windows and copy the following lines into that file

```yml
    [wsl2]
    kernelCommandLine = vsyscall=emulate
```

Then just restart your Docker engine.

Comment: Restarting docker engine was not enough for me. I had to restart my PC

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the Docker engine from WSL2 back-end to Hyper-V

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/docker-exited-with-139-when-running-cloudera-quickstart/td-p/298586